# Error during Check target DBMS connection

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-workbench, mariadb

I am trying to migrate database from SQL Server is in `172.16.12.116` to MariaDB (Windows) is in `172.16.12.107` through MySQL Workbench 6.1.4.

Source selection got succeeded. But when I am trying to connect to target I am getting this error:

> Error during Check target DBMS connection: MySQLError("Host '172.16.12.116' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server (code 1130)"): error calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.connect

What possibly could be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench only works with MySQL servers, with the exception of migration sources (which can be Postgres, Sybase and others).

What you can do however is first to migrate to a MySQL server and then dump the imported data and import that in MariaDB. Might require a few adjustments then.